# New top bar pushes close/flag dialogs

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, vote-to-close, top-bar

I don't know if its just me, but the new nav bar seems to be adjusting the placement of the flag and close dialogs. They seem to be centered on the content area - so that its appearing that they are lower than the true center of the page. It just feels awkward not to have it front and center of the whole frame since they seem to be on the same plane/layer as the nav bar.

The upload picture modal doesn't seem to be affected.

[image]

Comment: It's not just you, compared to sites without the new top bar, the dialog is indeed pushed down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra padding / margin was being applied to these incorrectly.